# ListView doesn't show

Tags: android, listview, onconfigurationchanged

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  setContentView(R.layout.layout_currently);
  if(dHolder.getCurrentItems() == null)
  {
      defineView();
      new LoadCurrent().execute(currentItems);
  }
  else
  {
      try {
          ArrayList<CurrentlyItem> privateCItem = dHolder.getCurrentItems();
          Log.d("ListSize", "There is " + privateCItem.size() + " elements on list");
          int resID = R.layout.current_item;
          Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
          aa = new CurrentAdapter(this, resID, privateCItem, display.getRotation());
          currentListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.currentListView);
          currentListView.setAdapter(aa);
          aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(" - ERROR", e.toString());
    }

  }
}
```

This is a code which should handle screen rotation... Everything works with no error at all but List View doesn't show... I receive ArrayList with 140 elements (reported by Log.d in code) but for some reason List View doesn't show...

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: can you post the `getView` method of your extended `ArrayAdapter`?

Comment: It is a quite long code, but it works perfectly if called onCreate ... Can you please tell me which part of the code is relavant...

Comment: I believe is is problem in filling old activity's data...

Comment: If your UI is mostly a `ListView`, you should not be using `onConfigurationChanged()`, anyway. Please remove the `android:configChanges` attribute from your manifest and use `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` to pass your model data (e.g., list contents) and such from the old activity instance to the new one.